# Have column extend to bottom of browser with an empty header, and using min-height

Tags: css

This is a continuation of a question I asked here: 
[Have column extend to bottom of browser with an empty header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700976/have-column-extend-to-bottom-of-browser-with-an-empty-header)

I added a min-height to main-content with erratic results. It just doesnt work.

Anyone know how to make it so that I can use min-height?

and this method doesnt take into account if the content extends beyond the bottom of the browser

Comment: what do expect min-height to do? and what do you expect to happen when content extends beyond the browser?

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to make main-content a fixed size, no matter how big the content, you can add `overflow:scroll` to div#main-content. This will turn the white main-content into a scrollable area if content [overflows](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).